# Imprimir los ceros de una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema en mi código el cual no me imprime los ceros que contiene una variable. Un ejemplo simplificado de lo que estoy intentando hacer es el siguiente:

```
a = 0
print (00+a)
```

Output:

```
0
```

Me gustaría imprimir `000`. ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Si es posible `print ('%03d'%int(00+a))` o `str(a).zfill(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Respuesta corta

Si, si lo que tratas de sumar son cadenas.
No, si lo que tratas de sumar son enteros o flotantes.

#### Respuesta larga

Cuando escribes 00 (sin las comillas), Python interpreta que estás escribiendo el número 0.

Cuando haces esta cuenta `00 + 0` en realidad es el equivalente a `0 + 0` que sabemos que da 0. De ahí que te dé ese resultado.

#### Solución

En lugar de sumar numeros, suma cadenas. NO es lo mismo (programáticamente hablando) la cadena "000" que el numero 000 (equivalente a 0).
Para que Python considere como cadena algo, ese algo debe de estar entre comillas:

```
a = "0"
print ("00"+a)
```

La suma cadena1+cadena2 hace que cadena2 aparesca luego de cadena1. Por ejemplo la suma `"hola" + "mundo"` es igual a `"holamundo"`.

El problema es que el resultado de esta cuenta no es un entero, si no una cadena. Pero aun así visualmente logra lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y por tu completa explicación.